# How do I find the largest negative integer in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

let test12 = [-1, -2, -3];

I'm stuck on this one.  I used the below on positive integers but I'm not sure what to change for negatives.

```js
let test = [1 , 2, 3];

var largest= 0;

for (i=0; i<=test.length;i++){
    if (test[i]>largest) {
        largest=test[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```

Comment: What sort of output do you want for that input, `-1` or `-3`?

Comment: `I used the below on positive integers` I hope you never come across an array with a very very big number in it

Comment: your code in the post doesn't work. It will just print the first element of the array, change `i<=largest` to `i<=test9.length`

Answer (score 2):

> largest negative integer in an array

Your question can have 3 interpretations:

1. The negative integer that is farthest from `0`
2. The negative integer that is closest to `0`
3. The largest number in general (you might be struggling if an all negative integer array comes along, because you initialize min to 0)

Just to clarify, smallest is 'farthest from zero'. But here's all three ways :) :

```js
const ints = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

const negativeInts = ints.filter(i => i < 0)

const smallestNegative = Math.min(...negativeInts)
const largestNegative = Math.max(...negativeInts)
const largestOverall = Math.max(...ints)
console.log({smallestNegative, largestNegative, largestOverall}) // -3, -1, 2
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `largest` to `-Infinity` rather than `0`. You also need to iterate over the input array's length, not `0` to `largest`:

```js
let test12 = [-1, -2, -3];
var largest = -Infinity;
for (i = 0; i < test12.length; i++) {
  if (test12[i] > largest) {
    var largest = test12[i];
  }
}
console.log(largest);
```

Another method would be to spread into `Math.max`:

```js
let test12 = [-1, -2, -3];
console.log(
  Math.max(...test12)
);
```

Comment: `Math.max` is -1 the *largest* negative, or is `-3`?

Comment: No, `-Infinity` is the lowest negative. `-1` is the largest number in `[-1, -2, -3]`

Comment: but the question asks for largest negative - largest, being greatest in magnitude -3 is more negative than -1 :p that's my interpretation of the question with code that doesn't even work :p

Comment: Semantically, I'd say that `-1` *would* be the "largest negative" in the array, guess I'll ask OP to clarify

Comment: I'm with @Bravo  on this one. Largest is usually equated with magnitude. I don't think anyone would consider -1 the largest negative.

Comment: Also, your code will fail in case even a single positive integer is present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Largest negative would be `-244`, so you can sort and get the first index.

```js
let arr = [-1, -2, -244, -7],
    [largets] = arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(largets);
```

Comment: Why would you perform such a complicated process just to find a min, when you can use: `console.log(Math.min(...arr))`? Also, Why would you sort with O(n*log(n)), when you could just search in O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```js
var array = [-155,3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, -89, -32,115,-150];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a programming solution ,like an edit that your program needs to perform even if an all negative array is given, then try this :

```js
let test = [-10, -1, -2, -3];
// just Assign largest to the first element in test.
// the largest int might not be greater than zero,
// but will definitely be larger that any other element in the array. 
var largest= test[0];

for (i=0; i<=test.length;i++){
    if (test[i]>largest) {
        largest=test[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```